# App force opens Play Store when I try to open Chrome

Tags: google-play-store, chrome-for-android

I downloaded and installed GO Launcher and there was an icon preinstalled with it. I clicked on it once accidentally, and it opened in the Play Store. Now when I try to use Chrome anytime, it force opens the Play Store right away to Spartan Wars. I can't use Chrome at all now and this is driving me nuts.

I'd like to fix this issue without having to uninstall GO Launcher, since I just it set up. In the meantime, I downloaded Firefox so I can ask this question.

I also installed the game then uninstalled it to no avail. Could someone explain why and how to prevent it?

Comment: I'm not using Chrome; but could it be it has a "start page" defined in its settings? If so, this is what was probably done by that "icon". Simply remove that startpage from the config (or set it to something else).

Comment: Chrome has a bug which cause it to keep the last intent it received from another application when you open chrome normally. For example: you made a search on Google Search/Now, you clicked on a link that opened in Chrome, then until you force close chrome, restart your phone or something, every time you will open Chrome normally, the link you clicked on Google Search/Now will reopen...
So I'd say this is the chrome step that helped you (you can put your answer in a answer yourself and accept it)

Answer (score 1):

[From OP themself](https://android.stackexchange.com/revisions/63199/2):

---

I got it fixed although I'm not sure which one of these things did the trick.

I went into the Application Manager and scrolled across to "All"

I then scrolled down Google Play Store and cleared the data.

Next I scrolled down to Chrome, I force stopped it, cleared the data, then turned it off and then back on.

Doing that seemed to do the trick, although I'm not sure which one of those steps was the right one.

Answer (score -2):

`settings -> applications -> manage applications -> chrome -> clear defaults` might help you.